# Get the X509 certificate alias from a Soap Envelope

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, x509certificate, ws-security

i have a java webservice developed with spring-boot, using SOAP 1.2 and ws-security with X509 certificates. I'd like to be able to read the alias of the private key being used by the client.
I thought i could get this information from the SOAP Envelope, but I've been struggling for hours on this to no avail. Is it even possible?

The problem is that the keystore jks being used on the server ( that contains the list of all the client public keys) needs to be able to distinguish between different clients, in order to encrypt the response correctly.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Convert xml string to org.w3c.dom.Document and you can get certificate node by tag name. Just replace tag name to what you should use.

```
Node certNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:X509Certificate").item(0);
String x509Cert = certNode.getTextContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finally got it.

I had to develop a spring-boot SmartEndPointInterceptor. Like this:

```
public class TrustSenderInterceptor extends Wss4jSecurityInterceptor implements SmartEndpointInterceptor {

Crypto                    crypto  = null;
public static final QName KEYINFO = new QName( "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", "KeyInfo" );

@Override
public boolean shouldIntercept( MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint ) {

    WebServiceMessage wsMessage = messageContext.getRequest();
    SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) wsMessage;      

    Document doc = soapMessage.getDocument();
    RequestData requestData = initializeRequestData( messageContext );
    //get the soap Header element
    Element soapHeaderElement = WSSecurityUtil.getSOAPHeader( doc );
    Element wssSecurityElement = null;
    X509Certificate cert = null;
    try {
        //read the part of the soap Header starting with <wsse:Security>
        wssSecurityElement = WSSecurityUtil.getSecurityHeader( soapHeaderElement, null, true );
        //read the certificate
        cert = getCertificateFromKeyInfo( requestData, wssSecurityElement );
    } catch ( WSSecurityException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error( "TrustSenderInterceptor - Can't read the Certificate INFO" );
    }

    //get the certificate's subjectDN component
    Principal subjectDN = cert.getSubjectDN();
    //read the CN
    String alias = extractCN( subjectDN.toString() );
    //finally, i set the alias just found in the certificate. In this way i can always pick the correct key in the keystore and handle multiple clients with different keypairs ;-)
    setSecurementEncryptionUser( alias );

    return true;
}

private X509Certificate getCertificateFromKeyInfo( RequestData data, Element securityHeader ) throws WSSecurityException {

    X509Certificate[] certs;

    EncryptedKeySTRParser decryptedBytes;
    //navigate <wsse:Security> and search for ds:KeyInfo
    Element secTokenRef = getSecTokenRef( securityHeader );
    //Initialize WSS4J parser
    STRParserParameters encryptedEphemeralKey1 = new STRParserParameters();
    data.setWsDocInfo( new WSDocInfo( securityHeader.getOwnerDocument() ) );
    //Set the crypto object. It is necessary.        
    data.setDecCrypto( crypto );
    encryptedEphemeralKey1.setData( data );
    encryptedEphemeralKey1.setStrElement( secTokenRef );
    decryptedBytes = new EncryptedKeySTRParser();
    //parse the key
    STRParserResult refList = decryptedBytes.parseSecurityTokenReference( encryptedEphemeralKey1 );
    certs = refList.getCertificates();

    if ( certs == null || certs.length < 1 ) {
        logger.error( "TrustSenderInterceptor - Couldn't find any certificate" );
        return null;
    }
    return certs[0];
}

private static Element getSecTokenRef( Element soapSecurityHeader ) throws WSSecurityException {

    for ( Node currentChild = soapSecurityHeader.getFirstChild(); currentChild != null; currentChild = currentChild.getNextSibling() ) {
        if ( WSConstants.SIGNATURE.getLocalPart().equals( currentChild.getLocalName() ) && WSConstants.SIGNATURE.getNamespaceURI().equals( currentChild.getNamespaceURI() ) ) {
            Element signatureEl = (Element) currentChild;
            for ( Node innerCurrentChild = signatureEl.getFirstChild(); innerCurrentChild != null; innerCurrentChild = innerCurrentChild.getNextSibling() ) {
                if ( KEYINFO.getLocalPart().equals( innerCurrentChild.getLocalName() ) && KEYINFO.getNamespaceURI().equals( innerCurrentChild.getNamespaceURI() ) ) {
                    return (Element) innerCurrentChild.getFirstChild();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private String extractCN( String subjectCN ) {
    String ret = null;
    String[] parts = subjectCN.split( "," );
    ret = parts[0].split( "=" )[1];
    return ret;
}

public void setSignatureCrypto( Crypto c ) {
    this.crypto = c;
}
```

I hope it helps somebody out there! Thanks to [this](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/code/projects/EDELIVERY/repos/domibus/browse/Domibus-MSH/src/main/java/eu/domibus/ebms3/receiver/TrustSenderInterceptor.java?at=538608f9a0486ed89cdc9def0ac2cf1dce9da2c2) for the huge inspiration.